# New tag proposals

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking a couple of questions this morning, I found myself searching for some appropriate tags and couldn't find them. I would propose adding:

1. Competition - For addressing questions about beer competitions, rules, entry, awards, etc.
2. Social - Social impact of beer consumption, from the positive to the negative
3. Advertising - How beer is advertised, or related to public promotion of beer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the tags and see what sticks.

This is an early private beta so anyone can add tags. We can merge/synonimize tags as needed and remove/add when needed right now.

Really meta discussion should be had only if tags are in dispute.

Comment: Educate me. :) I could not find a link to add a tag.

Comment: Just type it in the tags area; if you type something it recognizes you'll get the pop-up completions, but if what you type is new you can still do it.